# Multiple device (phones) synchronization - React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, synchronization

I'm trying to create Lightshow which will start on mobiles for all users (it can be up to 2000-3000 users) at the same time. All users will use internet (Wi-Fi or mobile data). At our FE we are using Apollo with subcriptions, which works like a charm.

But the problem is, that User A can obtain the subscription event sooner that the User B. It means that User A will start playing sooner than the User B, and this is a problem because we have lighshow schema and users can't start earlier or later. As a user you will see the difference immediately and it isn't looking good.

What I saw is that the delay difference can be 300ms. Mostly is around 180ms+- between android (Xiaomi mi 9) vs ios (iPhone11). If we compare two ios devices iPhone 11 vs iPhone 13 the difference is around 50-100ms. Is there way how to wipe this difference, or at least lower it to, for all devices for example 40-60ms ?

From BE we are sending the server time(utc+0) when the lightshow will start in timestamp => in FE i am adding 10 seconds to provide all devices time to solve the functionality, so the start is delayed -> "timestamp + 10 seconds".

In FE I'm using library "react-native-ntp-client" to get same time on all type of devices (ios/android because what i discovered each device has a little bit different time). Then i am calculating the difference between the "start" and "ntpTime" and provide it as timeout to my setTimeout function which will trigger the start of the lightshow.

Down below i am providing the example, how i am working with the screen where is the lightshow.

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import ntpClient from 'react-native-ntp-client';

export const LightshowScreen: React.FC<
  LightshowScreenProps<'Lightshow'>
> = ({route}) => {
  const {data, loading} = useSubscription(JOIN_LIGHTSHOW_SUBSCRIPTION, {
    variables: {lightshowId: route.params.lightshow.id},
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const getServerTime = async (lightshowStartAt: number) => {
      // Delay start 10s to provide enough time to finish our functions - lightshowStartAt is timestamp from our server
      const lightshowStart = dayjs.unix(lightshowStartAt).add(10, 's');

      ntpClient.getNetworkTime('time.cloudflare.com', 123, (error, date) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error('Cant connect', error);
          return;
        }

        console.log('NTP client date - ', date); // Mon Jul 08 2013 21:31:31 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))
        let ntpTime = dayjs(date);

        // Diff in ms
        const diff = lightshowStart.diff(ntpTime);

        // After this timeout all devices should start play at the same time
        setTimeout(() => {
          lightshowStartHandler();
        }, diff);
      });
    };

    if (data && data?.joinLightshow.started) {
      const lightshowData = data.lightshow;
      getServerTime(lightshowData.startedAt);
    }
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data?.joinLightshow?.finished) {
      lightshowFinishHandler();
    }
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <View style={style.container}>
      ....
    </View>
  );
};
```

Thanks for all your comments and ideas ;)

Comment: You could use a socket connection to send the start signal rather than relying on a timestamp.  I can't say for sure whether this will lead to better synchronization, which is too bad, because it could be a fair amount of effort.  But it "feels" like it should be more reliable than syncing based on timestamp.

Comment: Well Apollo subcriptions use Graphql-ws. So i am using it. The problem is that the message from this subscription come to devices at different times. So i can not rely on this.

Device A will obtain message after 30ms, Device B obtains the message after 70ms, the next one after 200ms and so on, so its imposible to synchronize devices only with websocket. So I need another checker where I will sync all devices together, after obtained message from websocket and the lightshow will start at exact time on all devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is REALLY hard.  Synchronizing devices like this is difficult.  Doing it when you don't own and control the hardware is next to impossible.  Quite frankly I don't think you'll ever get what you want.

A timestamp will never work.  For one, the devices won't all have the same time.  They'll all be off slightly.  Your next idea will be to send them the time from a central source-  like your server.  The problem with that is that sending the data will take different, random amounts of time to each device.  You can try to guesstimate the delay by calculating the round trip time of a dozen packets beforehand, but it's still a guess and may not be accurate on the next one.  NTP is good for getting devices close to the same time, but does not have the kind of accuracy you want it to.

Even if it did get the type of accuracy you want-  Android is not a real time OS.  Not is iPhone.  Even if you set an alarm for 12:00:00, it will not fire exactly at 12:00:00.000.  It will fire some time after that, when the OS has spare time, spare cores, and thinks your app is the most important one to schedule.  That can take several hundred milliseconds.  There are OSes that can give you the promise you want.  They're called real time OSes, and they're typically used in embedded devices that cannot fail, like medical devices and controllers for expensive machines.  They're a completely different method of writing an OS than a consumer device uses.

I'd really suggest rethinking your requirements and becoming more realistic about them.  There are techniques that can get you what you want, but not over the internet on random hardware on consumer OSes.

Also, if you're trying to do this-  I really wouldn't recommend using React Native, which is running an interpreter in a garbage collected language that's going to have really random timing.  You want to write at least the launcher in C, as it's the most predicatble way of doing it.

But really, rethink your requirements.  Why does it need to start within 50ms of each other?  Does it really matter when you're doing things over the internet if people are out of sync by a second?

Comment: Gabe thank you for answer. I really appretiate it. I just took time to think about what you wrote. 

"Why does it need to start within 50ms of each other?" => Try to imagine, that you have lightshow schema for exact song which is playing and you want to synch, all devices to "blink" at the same time (for example the light is paired to beats in the music.) or at least with the lowest delay possible. 

I was thinking that the whole initialization of the lightshow I will try to write in Native, same as I wrote the switching on/off the light, maybe this will help a little bit?

Comment: I also found, that it can be solved via data transmitted through ultrasonic messages in the music. But I am not native developer, because my main focus is JS atm, so I dont think I am able to write this functionality in native quickly. That's why I am trying to figure it out, how it could work through Wi-Fi and JS.